How to use multiple middlewares in laravel 11?
I'm getting

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://host/endpoint' from origin
'http://host' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight
request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok
status."

when I use both CorsMiddleware and AuthMiddlware (NOTE: Both are custom middlewares)
Bootstrap/App.php:
 ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            'CorsMiddleware' => CorsMiddleware::class,
            'AuthMiddleware' => AuthMiddleware::class
        ]);
    })

Routes/Api.php:
 Route::controller(controller::class)->group(
     function () {
        Route::get('/sample/index', 'index');
        ... other routes
    }
)->middleware('CorsMiddleware');

I'm expecting my AuthMiddleware to check if the requestor is authenticated or something like that.
Thank you for your answers!

You haven't assigned AuthMiddleware to your routes that you should since it is a custom middleware. And if You want to use both middleware on some routes then i suggest to use middleware group and inside middleware group use Controller group.check the link https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#route-group-middleware
